Application using spring cloud stream with both gcp pub sub and rabbit bindings fails
I am trying to build a simple test spring boot app to consume messages from both GCP pubsub and RabbitMq using spring cloud stream.
I am facing issue when trying use spring.cloud.stream.binders
I am using below dependencies

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:3.0.0.RELEASE'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.0.0.RELEASE'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder:1.2.8.RELEASE'

Below yml config causes application to fails. The gcp pub sub fails stating that it could not find PubSubAdmin bean.
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        enabled: true
      project-id: projectId
      credentials:
        location: file:/Users/user/.config/gcloud/application_credentials.json
    stream:
      bindings:
        rabbit1: # The input binding name
          destination: rabbit-test-queue
          group: rabbit-test-queue  # Consumer group for the input channel
          binder: rabbit
          consumer:
            bind-queue: false
            declare-exchange: false
            queue-name-group-only: true
        pubsub1:
          destination: topic  # Specifies the topic name.
          group: subscription  # Defines the consumer group.
          binder: pubsub
      binders:
        # Define RabbitMQ binder
        rabbit:
          type: rabbit
          default-candidate: true
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                username: guest
                password: guest
        # Define the GCP Pub/Sub binder
        pubsub:
          type: pubsub # Reference your actual custom binder class
          default-candidate: false
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                gcp:
                  pubsub:
                    project-id: projectID
                    credentials:
                      location: file:/Users/user/.config/gcloud/application_credentials.json
                    binder:
                      auto-create-subscriptions: false
                      auto-create-topics: false

I can make this work if I do not specify binders under stream but instead use specific provider config
Below yml config works
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        enabled: true
      project-id: projectId
      credentials:
        location: file:/Users/user/.config/gcloud/application_credentials.json
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          rabbit1:
            consumer:
              bind-queue: false
              declare-exchange: false
              queue-name-group-only: true
      gcp:
        pubsub:
          default:
            consumer:
              auto-create-resources: false
          bindings:
            input1:
              consumer:
                subscription-name: subscription
                auto-create-resources: false
          binder:
            auto-create-subscriptions: false
            auto-create-topics: false
      bindings:
        input1:
          destination: topic     # Specifies the topic name.
          group: subscription   # Defines the consumer group.
          binder: pubsub
        rabbit1: # The input binding name
          destination: rabbit-test-queue
          group: rabbit-test-queue  # Consumer group for the input channel
          binder: rabbit
          consumer:
            bind-queue: false
            declare-exchange: false
            queue-name-group-only: true

Is this expected behaviour or do I need to disable some auto configuration or add some other dependencies.
I see that the PubSubBinderConfiguration class has @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Binder.class)
